# chords outside of scale

Tags: theory

Billy Joel's "Don't go Changing" in DMaj uses parallel scales and secondary dominant and I get that, but in the bridge the progression is in the key of D

G IV
A V
Gm7 borrowed IV
B7 ?
Em ii
A V
D I
D7 I
Am Borrowed V

What is the B7?

Answer (score 4):

The B7 is a secondary dominant of the Em chord that immediately follows, which you've already acknowledged is a ii chord.

Comment: B74 is *the*dominant of ii, Em. It's labelled *a* secondary dominant as the dominant of the key, D is A.

Answer (score 3):

It often sounds good to precede a chord with its dominant, and that's what B7 is doing here, preceding Em.

But don't fall into the trap of thinking that because some chromatic chords can be described as secondary dominants, or as 'borrowed' from somewhere, that all chromatic chords MUST be justified by one of those reasons.  You can use any chord you like.  Sometimes there's a functional analysis, or a 'borrowing' justification, sometimes there isn't.   Both are fine.